# If $z\in\mathbb C$ with $|z|\leqslant\frac{4}{5}$, then $\sum_{n\in S}z^n\neq-\frac{20}{9}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, summation, contest-math

Let $z$ be a complex number with $|z|\le\tfrac{4}{5}$. If $S\subset\mathbb N^+$ is a finite set, then I'd like to show  that
$$\sum_{n\in S}z^n\neq-\frac{20}{9}\,.$$
This problem is from an exam in Bejing as of today, and I find this is a very nice problem.

I have no idea how to access it, maybe use Newton's identity to  solve it.
Could someone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

Not a final answer, but some lead I hope:

I can see that for $r=\frac 45$ then $-\frac{20}{9}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-r)^{2k+1}$ so as to accumulate the maximum negative values possible.

And this is more than that if either $r<\frac 45$ or sum is incomplete.

I guess we have to prove that negative contributions cannot exceed this for a $z$ with random argument.

Comment: I see many upvotes on this incomplete answer during the bounty period and I'm grateful, but unfortunately I fear I'm not being able to offer a full solution. In particular I don't see a way to handle the lacunary trigonometric series, nor to prove that $z$ must be real to reach the minimum for instance. I tried to explore some ways, but this was inconclusive...

Comment: The solution most likely is going to involve some clever triangle inequality usage. The naive one yields an upper bound of $\dfrac{20}{5},$ when trying to argue by contradiction. Clearly, some nice argument of splitting the set $S$ to subsets is the way to go probably whilst keeping in mind that the odd powers sum to $-\dfrac{20}{9}$

Answer (score 3):

This one can be done by seriously partitioning the angle of $z$ and also the size of $|z|$, and proving the following strengthened claim:

Assume that $z\in \mathbb{C}$, with $|z|\leq r<1$, then for any subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$,$$
Re(\sum_{n\in S}z^n)\ge -\frac{r}{1-r^2}
$$
Equality can be achieved at $z=-r$, and $S=2\mathbb{N}+1$.

The following is a tricky proof:

Notice that:
$$
Re(\sum_{n\in S}z^n)=\frac 1 2Re(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}z^n)+\frac 1 2[Re(\sum_{n\in S}z^n-\sum_{n\notin S }z^n)]
$$
And we have:
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}
$$,
and
$$
|\sum_{n\in S}z^n-\sum_{n\notin S }z^n|\leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|z|^n=\frac{1}{1-r}
$$
Therefore,
$$
Re(\sum_{n\in S}z^n)\ge \frac 1 2[Re(\frac{1}{1-z})-\frac{1}{1-r}]
$$
And we only need to prove that
$$
Re(\frac{1}{1-z})\ge \frac{1}{1+r}
$$
Take $z=x+yi,x^2+y^2\leq r^2$.
$$
Re(\frac{1}{1-z})=\frac{1-x}{(1-x)^2+y^2}\ge \frac{1-x}{1-2x+r^2}\ge \frac{1}{1+r}\Longleftrightarrow (1-r)x\ge r^2-r
$$
Since $x\ge -r, (1-r)x\ge -r+r^2$, the claim follows.